# Embedded video in iPhone with smooth transition to MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, embedded-resource

In the new American Idol app there are embedded videos that, if you tap them, start playing and showing "pause" and "augment" buttons. When you tap the augment button, you get an animation that smoothly launches the full screen MPMoviePlayerController. Do you know how did they make it?

[image: American Idol Official]

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something like this by adding a gesture tap on that and implement the logic  of the gesture. On a tap I have added a view with buttons like share (in my case). I am sorry I don't have that code anymore.

Comment: The inline video can be implemented with a UIWebView and HTML5 <video>, but the problem here is the transition to full screen mode. There must be a place where you say the video to stop playing in the web view and continue in the MPMoviePLayerController.

Comment: Is the video came from youTube or the video is in your server? because in my situation it was in my server (much easier)

Comment: Thanks IOS DEV. The video is in a server and the problem I'm facing is reproducing the American Idol's behaviour when you tap the full screen button and it launches a transition to show the same video you was seeing in the WebView but in a MPMoviePlayer Controller way.